# Communication between Android app and Java SE via USB

Tags: java, android, putty

Please help. I can't find on the internet a simple example made of 2 apps ( one that will run on local PC using Java SE and one that runs on an Android Device ) that communicates via USB with the Java SE app. I also had tried different apps from Google store that communicates with Putty ( via serial ) but failed at the phase of making the connection. I am pretty sure that I had set correct for both apps (the "Serial Line", speed, data bits, and so on )

Answer (score 0):

Just figure it out. The answer is in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNJ84zaXybU

From the Desktop/Android app, I couldn't detect the serial port because I am using a regular USB cable. For this, to work I need an OTG (On to Go) cable/adapter.